# Get distance along one direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get the distance calculated within the y axis point? Such that the value is shown when the two objects are away from each other only in y axis and not in x or z axis.

```
float Distance_To_Top = Vector3.Distance (One.transform.position, Two.transform.position);
```

Comment: `gameObjec1.transform.position.y - gameObjec2.transform.position.y` ?

Comment: As MathewHD says .. quite trivial and even more efficient than calculating a vectorial magnitude ;)

Comment: Thank you. I thought Vector3.Distance() was more of a good approach.

Comment: @Saif well yes if you want the absolute distance in all 3 axis ;)

Comment: Assuming you want the distance between the centre of the two game objects (y component only) then @MathewHD has the correct solution. Otherwise if you are looking for distance between meshes along the Y axis it would involve the renderer component and would require more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more general case, you can find the distance between any two points measured in a single direction by using `Vector3.Dot` with a normalized direction vector:

```
Vector3 differenceDirection = Vector3.up;

float difference = Vector3.Dot(differenceDirection, 
        Two.transform.position - One.transform.position);
```

And, `difference` can tell you about their relative positioning, too:

- If `difference > 0`, `Two` is along `differenceDirection` from `One` by `difference`.
- If `difference < 0`, `One` is along `differenceDirection` from `Two` by `difference`.